# Vim higlight : multiple values to a key

Tags: vim

I want to make vim not only bold my current line but also to underline it.

My current .vimrc looks like this:

```
hi cursorline term=bold cterm=bold guibg=Grey40  
set cursorline
```

is it possible to add a value to my cterm?

Something like

```
cterm=bold&underline
```

OR

```
cterm=bold cterm+=underline
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a comma:

```
cterm=bold,underline
```

as explained in `:help attr-list`:

```
attr-list is a comma separated list (without spaces) of the
following items (in any order):

    bold
    underline
    undercurl       not always available
    reverse
    inverse         same as reverse
    italic
    standout
    NONE            no attributes used (used to reset it)
```